# DB2 sorting by lowercase uppercase - problem

Tags: db2, sorting

I'm struggling with DB2 - sorting by Polish letters with diacritics and uppercase/lowercase. When I created a database using:

```
CREATE DATABASE P1DS8 AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES ON '/home/db2inst1' DBPATH ON '/home/db2inst1' USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY PL COLLATE USING SYSTEM_912_PL PAGESIZE 32 K
```

Sorting by Polish letters works properly, however ascending sorting returns results ordered by lowercase as first aAbB... How I can change this setting to revert results to AaBb..?

Is the 'COLLATE' section is responsible for all aspects of sorting? (Specific language letters, lowercase, uppercase etc. )

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use the UCA (Unicode Collating Algorithm): the `COLLATE` value would be something like `UCA500R1_LPO_CU` for Polish and uppercase first. [More info here.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0050489.html)

Note that you cannot change the collating setting of an existing database; you would have to create a new one with the required collation and move your data.

Answer (score 0):

The `collate` is responsible for the sorting order. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0006812.html for some explanation.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you what other sort order you need to choose for polish letters. IBM might know.